# Using AJAX with two select boxes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have a view containing two select boxes: company and employee. Both have a blank option and when a company is selected, it populates the employees based on the selected company. This works just fine. My issue is that when I submit a form that fails validation (as expected) and I select a company once more once the 'new' view renders again in extensions#create, my 'get' AJAX call has changed from **/servers/1/extensions/get_company_employees (correct)** to **/servers/1/get_company_employees (incorrect)** and is returning 404 Not found. Why is this happening and what should I do to remedy this? All relevant code is listed below

### routes.config

```
resources :servers do
  scope module: 'servers' do
    resources :extensions, shallow: true
  end
end

# Ajax call
get 'servers/:id/extensions/get_company_employees', to: 'servers/extensions#get_company_employees', as: 'get_company_employees'
```

### app/controllers/servers/extensions_controller.rb

```
class Servers::ExtensionsController < ApplicationController

  def get_company_employees
    @server = Server.find(params[:id])
    @extension = @server.extensions.build
    @path = [@server, @extension]

    @companies = Company.all
    @employees = Employee.where("company_id = ?", params[:company_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def new
    @server = Server.find(params[:server_id])
    @extension = @server.extensions.build
    @path = [@server, @extension]

    @companies = Company.all
    @employees = Employee.none
  end

  def create
    @server = Server.find(params[:server_id])
    @extension = @server.extensions.build(extension_params)
    @extension.password = "pass"
    if @extension.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully created extension"
      redirect_to @extension
    else
      @path = [@server, @extension]
      @companies = Company.all
      @employees = Employee.none
      flash.now[:error] = "Failed to create extension"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private
    def extension_params
      params.require(:extension).permit(:value, :password, :employee_id, :server_id, :phone_id)
    end
end
```

### app/views/servers/extensions/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@path) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(:company) %>
    <%= select_tag "company", options_from_collection_for_select(@companies, "id", "name"), include_blank: "Select a company" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label(:employee) %>
    <%= f.collection_select :employee_id, @employees, :id, :full_name, include_blank: "Select an employee" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

### app/views/servers/extensions/get_company_employees.js.coffee

```
$("#extension_employee_id").empty()
.append("<option>Select an employee</option>")
.append("<%= j options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, :id, :full_name) %>")
```

### app/assets/javascripts/servers/extensions.coffee

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'page:load', '#company', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'get_company_employees',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        company_id: $("#company option:selected").val()
      }

  $(document).on 'change', '#company', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'get_company_employees',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        company_id: $("#company option:selected").val()
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have now specified complete URL in ajax call
It should be something like this in both cases.

```
$.ajax "/servers/"+ id +"/extensions/get_company_employees',
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'script'
  data: {
    company_id: $("#company option:selected").val()
  }
// store and fetch id attribute from page in any of the dom element
```

Ideally you should write a function for your ajax call which can be called wherever required   and code redundancy can be reduced.